# Installing SQLAlchemy with Poetry causes an AttributeErrorr

Tags: python, python-poetry

When installing with pip, `pip install sqlalchemy` all is ok.

When installing with poetry I am getting the error

```
➜  backend poetry add sqlalchemy
Using version ^1.4.23 for SQLAlchemy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

  AttributeError

  'EmptyConstraint' object has no attribute 'allows'

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/poetry/core/version/markers.py:291 in validate
      287│
      288│         if self._name not in environment:
      289│             return True
      290│
    → 291│         return self._constraint.allows(self._parser(environment[self._name]))
      292│
      293│     def without_extras(self):  # type: () -> MarkerTypes
      294│         return self.exclude("extra")
      295│
➜  backend
```

Comment: same for me today

Comment: This looks like it is a solved bug. Maybe stackoverflow is not the best place for it though?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `poetry self update`, then `poetry update`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

poetry add sqlalchemy=1.4.22

This will solve your problem

Comment: This works but it is a stub. The same thing is with `alembic`.

Comment: It seems like something sql alchemy introduced in their newest release. 
I assume constraining alembic would also be a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading poetry itself: `pip install -U poetry`. Worked for me to resolve SQLAlchemy issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [fl_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68881810/33404) but `poetry self update` itself failed for me with an error saying:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.console'

From a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049090/33404) to a different question I learned that I had poetry installed using the older, now deprecated, `get-poetry.py`.

So I uninstalled poetry like so:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py > get-poetry

python get-poetry --uninstall
```

Then reinstalled it with the newer `install-poetry.py` as per [official installation instructions](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installation).

This finally made the original `AttributeError` go away.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, it seems to be a very recent problem.
The good news is that "poetry self update" fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading poetry to `1.1.8` may solve the issue.

e.g. use `poetry self update` (related [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#updating-poetry))

Check related poetry issue too:

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4410#issuecomment-902144234